# Using Haskell 'statistics' package for linear regression

Tags: haskell, statistics, linear-regression

I need to run linear regression on a set of measurement data. I understand that [statistics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics) is the go to library for the job. Description of `ols` function in the module `Statistics.Regression` indicates that it's the thing that I need. However it is not clear from the documentation how to represent my measurement data, e.g.

```
measurements = [(1.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.5), (3.0, 3.0)] :: [(Double, Double)]  -- (X, Y) coordinates of points
```

to the function whose signature is

```
ols :: Matrix   -- A has at least as many rows as columns.
    -> Vector   -- b has the same length as columns in A.
    -> Vector
```

and how to interpret the results.
I expect to get values `a = 1.5` and `b = 0.5` for the equation `y = a + bx`.

How must I construct the the input `Matrix` and `Vector`, and what will be in the resulting `Vector`?

Comment: I think you mean you expect `a = 0.5` and `b = 1.5`.

Comment: The line would cross the Y axis at `y = 1.5`. When `x = 0`, `y = a`

Comment: Ah, you wrote _a_ + _bx_. Uncommon to have it this way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somehow expected that a statistics library offers functions of some generality, so if you are after a simple case, you have to narrow down the offered functionality. Here, the library functions expects several causal variables instead of just one. Also, it uses vectors and matrices where you might want just plain lists.

To show how to use the library with a single causal variable, I will assume you want an interface using just ordinary Haskell data types, like this:

```
-- [(x0, y0), (x1, y1), , (x2, y2) ... ] -> ((a, b), r2)  for  y ≃ a + b*x
simpleRegression1 :: [(Double, Double)] -> ((Double, Double), Double)
```

It seems simpler to use `olsRegress` than `ols`, because:

1. there is no need of a Matrix data type
2. you get the y-intercept value (that's *a* in your notation) easily
3. you also get the goodness-of-fit coefficient from the same call

The code can be written as follows:

```
import qualified  Data.List              as  L
import qualified  Data.Vector.Unboxed    as  DVU
import qualified  Statistics.Regression  as  SR

-- [(x0, y0), (x1, y1), , (x2, y2) ... ] -> ((a, b), r2)  for  y ≃ a + b*x
simpleRegression1 :: [(Double, Double)] -> ((Double, Double), Double)
simpleRegression1 xyPairs =
   let  xList    = L.map  fst  xyPairs
        yList    = L.map  snd  xyPairs
        xVecList = [DVU.fromList  xList]
        yVec     =  DVU.fromList  yList
        (sv, r2) = SR.olsRegress xVecList yVec
        [b, a]   = DVU.toList sv
    in
        ((a,b), r2)
```

In our case, there is a single column vector, so `xVecList` has just one element.
As mentioned in the [olsRegress documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.2.0/docs/Statistics-Regression.html#v:olsRegress), the y-intercept “a” value is the last element of the output vector.

### Testing code:

```
main = do
    let  measurements = [(1.0, 1.9999), (2.0, 2.5001), (3.0, 2.9999)]
         ---- measurements = [(1.0, 2.0), (2.0, 2.5), (3.0, 3.0)]
         ((a,b), r2)  = simpleRegression1  measurements
    putStrLn $ "measurements = " ++ (show measurements)
    putStrLn $ "a = " ++ (show a) ++ "  b = " ++ (show b) ++
               "  r2 = " ++ (show r2)

    let  ypList   = L.map  (\x -> a+b*x)  (L.map fst measurements)
         diffList = L.zipWith  (-)  (L.map snd measurements)  ypList
    putStrLn $ "ypList = " ++ (show ypList)
    putStrLn $ "diffList = " ++ (show diffList)
```

### Test output:

```
measurements = [(1.0,1.9999),(2.0,2.5001),(3.0,2.9999)]
a = 1.4999666666666656  b = 0.5000000000000006  r2 = 0.9999999466666695
ypList = [1.999966666666666,2.4999666666666664,2.9999666666666673]
diffList = [-6.666666666599319e-5,1.3333333333376274e-4,-6.66666666675475e-5]
```

Note there is also a [LinearRegression module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-linreg-0.3/docs/Statistics-LinearRegression.html).

Answer (score 0):

Let me rewrite the signature of `ols` to reflect what it actually accomplishes, conceptually:

```
ols :: (VectorSpace u, VectorSpace v) => (u +> v) -> v -> u
```

where `+>` denotes a [linear function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map), which is what the matrix represents.

So, `u` is the result you want (i.e. the parameters `a` and `b`). The matrix argument is the (linear) function that maps such parameters to predictions for the actual measurements. So, that involves computing *a·x* + *b* at each of the *x* positions you have in the dataset.

In a more maths-inspired (rather than Matlab- or R-inspired) library, you would be able to write it roughly this way:

```
m :: Matrix
m = fromFunction $ \(a,b) -> fmap (\x -> a*x + b) [1,2,3])
```

And then the measurement vector of type `v` is the `y` values you have in the output, so you would evaluate

```
ols m [2, 2.5, 3]
```

In fact, in [`linearmap-category`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category) – which, unlike `statistics`, is properly typed – you can do that almost exactly this way:

```
> :m +Math.LinearMap.Category
> import Linear (V2(..), V3(..))
> lfun (\(V2 a b) -> fmap (\x -> a*x + b) (V3 1 2 3)) \$ V3 2 2.5 3
V2 0.4999999999999998 1.5000000000000018
```

In `statisics` you will, I suspect, yourself need to build the matrix out of the linear function. It's slightly fiddly but not difficult: building a matrix means simply putting in the possible basis-inputs `(1,0)` and `(0,1)`, evaluating the function for them (i.e. once for `a=1`, `b=0` and once for `a=0`, `b=1`) and noting the results for each all the `x` down as column vectors.

Comment: No, I don't understand that. I do not have a linear function. I have a set of spot values. I want the library routine give me the linear function that "best approximates" the values that I have. I.e. the `a` and `b` values for the linear function `f(x) = a + bx`

Comment: There's a common misconception here: “linear regression” does _not_ mean you're fitting a “linear” function, in the sense of a straight function (_affine_ is actually the correct term). In fact, you can as well linearly fit a polynomial or a sinusoidal function. The important bit is that the function is linear in _the fitting parameters_, i.e. when you double both `a` and `b` then the function output doubles as well. It is this property that, given any vector of `x` values, allows the corresponding outputs of \(_a,b_) ⟼ _a_ + _bx_ to be captured in a matrix.

Comment: after some reading I came up with this: `(predictor, responder) = both fromList $ unzip measurements; (regression, goodness) = olsRegress [predictor] responder; intercept = regression ! 1; coefficient = regression ! 0`. Predictor being a list of _one_ Vector because we have a single-predictor case. Resulting figures look reasonable to me. Is what I am doing correct? If so, I will post it as a self-answer.

Comment: Hm... ah, `olsRegress` automatically adds a column for the intercept, then that's right. (If it didn't do that, you could just add a column of all-1s.)